# html checkbox onChange methode in php

Tags: php, html, checkbox

Here is my problem, I know only html and php and I have no clue about how to use javascript... And all the solutions about my problems seems to be resolved in javascript and I wondered if there was a way to do it with php so that I could understand what I do.

I want to put a checkbox on the corner of my page (for instance "hide information") that would refresh the page automatically when checked and that would hide information on the page.

What I currently do is :

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['condition']))
    $_SESSION['condition'] = true;
else
    $_SESSION['condition'] = false;
?>
...
...
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hide" value="1" onChange="this.form.submit()" <?php if($_SESSION['hide']) echo "checked";?> > hide information
</form>
```

I am facing two problems :

1. the first one is that I want the checkbox to stay checked/unchecked when the page is refreshed.. I solve that poorly with my php code, but there surely exists something better to do that.
2. When the box is checked, the page is refresh with only "hide=1" as an url argument, but I would love to keep all the other arguments that were there before the page was refreshed. Is there a way to refresh the page and keep all the arguments while knowing that the box is checked/unchecked ?

thanks for your help, and sorry for my poor knowledge.

Comment: are you including any class in this file that handles the logic or all logic and html is in the same file?

Comment: no I include other files for logic/data

Comment: what you can do is when the form is submitted you have the values in `$_POST` and then you can display those submitted values in `input value="$_POST['field-data']"`' this way you dont lose the already form fields that have been filled and then use the `$_GET` to put your hide logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the second point of your question you can move the POST (or GET) array to the SESSION one and back with the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST) & count($_POST)) { $_SESSION['post'] = $_POST; }
if(isset($_SESSION['post']) && count($_SESSION['post'])) { $_POST = $_SESSION['post']; }
```

I use this to do exactly the same. When I reload the page I keep the posted values.

Regarding the first point you are already on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with how you've tried to solve problem 1.

Regarding the URL problem 2, either put session_start(); at the top of the page to get the session to work correctly.

Alternatively have hidden inputs in this pages' form and echo out the previous pages' POST values.

```
    <form action="" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="condition" value="<?php echo $_POST['condition']; ?>" />
       <!-- have hidden inputs from previous page here, plus your checkbox to retain post values from the previous page -->
    </form>
```

Although I'd recommend POST for this, you can do GET although it gets a bit messy like so:

```
<form action="thispage.php?condition=<?php echo $_GET['condition'];?>" />
```

Comment: The other fields come from another page, but you are right I could use the POST instead of GET. It should work.

Comment: I see, have a look at my revised answer.